# jQuery/ajax form submitting not working with multiple forms + modals not closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page on my site where I got n+1 forms (n being the number of images on the site)

I have this piece of javascript to submit the forms without the user seing it directly:

```
$('#commentform').on('submit', function(){
      $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
            var imgid = $(this).find("input[name='imageid']").val();
            $('#comment-'+imgid).modal('hide');
      },'json');
      return false;
   });
```

That code will submit the form in a modal like this one:

```
<div id='comment-<?php echo $image->id; ?>' class='modal hide fade' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
    <div class='modal-header'>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>×</button>
        <h3 id='myModalLabel'>Tilf&oslash;j kommentar til billede <?php echo $orig_name; ?></h3>
    </div>
    <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>order/do_updateComment/<?php echo $image->id; ?>" method="POST" id="commentform">
        <div class='modal-body'>
            <textarea name="comment" rows="3" class="span6" placeholder="Skriv din kommentar her..."><?php echo $image->comment; ?></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="imageid" value="<?php echo $image->id; ?>" />
        </div>
        <div class='modal-footer'>
            <button class='btn' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>Luk</button>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class='btn btn-primary' value="Gem kommentar" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

This works perfect for the *first* form on the page - all the rest gets submitted the wrong way (with a redirect to the submission page)

What am I missing here?  I am suspecting it to be because of the use of `id="commentform"` on all of the forms, but how else could this be done? I got one form on the site that needs to be submitted the normal way.

Also on a side-note, I want to close the modal once the submit has finished, which should be done with these lines of code:

```
var imgid = $(this).find("input[name='imageid']").val();
$('#comment-'+imgid).modal('hide');
```

inside the javascript (complete is in the top of the question)

However, that does not work either.. The modal stays open..

I am running the whole thing on Bootstrap 2.x with jquery 1.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference to $(this) is dropped when you're in the callback. Save the reference outside of the post and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

> I am suspecting it to be because of the use of id="commentform" on all of the forms

Correct, ids must be unique. Using classes is the common way to select multiple similar elements.

Comment: Allright, first problem solved.. Now I just need to figure out why the modals won't close?

Comment: Inserting a `console.log(img)` doesn't return anything, but so does a `console.log("DEBUG:")` - so it seems that it does not run the stuff in between it? Does the server have to return something special to the ajax query for it to continue executing the js?